# issue with java code . i cant find my mistake. Dog and Cat are undelined

Tags: java, polymorphism, netbeans-8

```
package Exersise3;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PetsDriver1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Object obj;
        System.out.print("Which type of pet do you prefer?\n"
            + "Enter d for dogs or c for cats: ");
        if (stdIn.next().equals("d")) {
            obj = new Dog();
        } else {
            obj = new Cat();
        }
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask a question within your question. Please show all code -- where's your Dog and Cat class code? Do they exist?

Comment: place your Dog, Cat in package Exersise3; or import Dog and Cat classes in to this class. look at my code snippet below.

Comment: More than likely it's an error with your package declaration; I would first take the dog and cat classes and put them into the same directory as your PetsDriver1 and see if it compiles, then I would work out the package declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know where the Dog or Cat class is. Here are the steps to telling the compiler how to create a new Dog or new Cat

1. Make sure that you have a Dog.java and a Cat.java file in your project. Even   if they are in the same folder as your PetsDriver, the compiler won't know to compile them unless you add them to your netbeans project.
2. Make sure that at the very least Dog.java contains

   `public class Dog {}`

   and Cat.java contains

   `public class Cat {}`
3. If the package declaration at the top of Dog.java or Cat.java is not

   `package Exercise3;`

   then you must import their package at the top of your PetsDriver1 class so that the compiler knows to look outside the Exercise3 package to find Cat or Dog. (i.e. if Dog.java's first line is "package Pet;" then in PetsDriver1.java put "import Pet.Dog;" right after "import java.util.Scanner")